# Auto Fit images when inserting in document

Tags: java, image, itext, rtf

I am trying to insert images to a rtf document using the iTextRtf api. Inserting part is done, however the images are not completely shown in the document due to their size. I have set a constant width and height while inserting the images, but in this case if an image is inserted of a lesser size, then that images is expanded to the constant width & height specified. Thus the image appears a bit blurry.

Can you suggest how I can auto fit the images so that they appear as it is. because when we copy & paste an image in a word document, they are inserted as it is.

Hope this makes some sense.

Thanks,
Anuj Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a check to see if the image is smaller than the constant width & height. If so you don't resize else you resize?